Overloads on Arrow Functions
I have:
type OnCloseType = {
  (gesture: 'close-button' | 'cancel' | 'escape'): void;
  (gesture: 'confirm', value: string): void;
  (gesture: string, value?: string): void;
};

const onClose: OnCloseType = (gesture, value) => {
    if (gesture === "confirm") {
        value // <= 'value' is possibly 'undefined'.
    } else {
        value
    }
}

I expect that value type can't ve undefined in the first if block. How can fix that?
Also I tried:
function onClose(gesture: 'close-button' | 'cancel' | 'escape'): void;
function onClose(gesture: 'confirm', value: string): void;
function onClose(gesture: string, value?: string): void {
    if (gesture === "confirm") {
        value // <= 'value' is possibly 'undefined'.
    } else {
        value
    }
}

It didn't work also.

If you know that value cannot be null in that block then you can append ! the "Non-null assertion operator" to tell the compiler that value cannot be null at that position.
e.g. value.substring( 1 ); // <= 'value' is possibly 'undefined' but value!.substring( 1 ); // All good

This doesn't have anything much to do with arrow functions per se, since function statements have the same issue. Also note that your two code blocks are not equivalent since your arrow function has three call signatures and your function statement has two. The implementation signature is not a call signature. Presumably you included that third signature in your arrow function type because you thought it was an implementation signature? But it wrecks what you're trying to express. Please [edit] to fix all this (e.g., just use your function statement version) and we can help.

(see prev comment) After you do that I'd say you're probably hitting the lack of ms/TS#22609 and the correct approach for the code as written here would be to abandon overloads in favor of a function accepting a rest parameter of a destructured discriminated union type, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?
